# How to access a port via OpenVpn only

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I've set up an openvpn server alongside an apache website that can only be accessed on port 8100 on the same machine. 
My /etc/openvpn/server.conf file looks like this:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ./easy-rsa2/keys/ca.crt
cert ./easy-rsa2/keys/server.crt
key ./easy-rsa2/keys/server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh ./easy-rsa2/keys/dh1024.pem # Diffie-Hellman parameter
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
# make sure clients can still connect to the internet
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Now I tried to let only clients connected to the vpn network access the website on apache via port 8100. So I defined a few iptables rules:

```
#!/bin/sh
# My system IP/set ip address of server
SERVER_IP="10.0.0.10"
# Flushing all rules
iptables -F
iptables -X
# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
# Allow incoming access to port 8100 from OpenVPN 10.8.0.1
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 8100 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -p tcp --sport 8100 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# outgoing http
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -p tcp --dport 8100 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --sport 8100 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Now when I connect to the server from my client computer and try to access the website on 10.0.0.10:8100, my browser can't open it. Will I have to forward traffic from tun0 to eth0? Or is there anything else I'm missing?

FYI: I'm running ubuntu server 12.04.1 LTS. Iptables is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using subnet/IP different than the one provided by OpenVPN, you probably need to allow the server to do NATting for this to work.

Run the following commands:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

You should fine tune the iptables rule to fit your need. This should get you working.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried that one but didn't help. But I think, I just gave a bad example since I used the server id 192.168.0.2 first. In this case, it's actually 10.0.0.10 for the server and 10.8.0.1 for the openvpn server.

Comment: 10.8.0.1/24 would't connect to 10.0.0.10 without some form of routing. Check you subnet configuration in your server.conf.